# How to print file names in find despite processing the result and grep

Tags: linux, bash

I have a directory with files to test, say file `A`, `B` and `C`.

To make things easy, let's assume I have a command I want to issue on each of these files and find the one that gives me a proper output.

I will need a pipe `myCommand fileName | grep ExpectedResult` (in my real case I was looking for a symbol in a library, so it was `readelf -s | grep MySymbol`).

I want to issue this command on a result of `find` command.

I find my result with

```sh
find . -name *.so -print0 | xargs -0 myCommand | grep ExpectedResult
```

This works ok, prints `ExpectedResult`.

What I want to receive is (assuming that the file I look for is `B`):

```sh
A
B
ExpectedResult
C
```

This way I could see in which file the result has been found. If I was just about to `grep` the content of the file, I would need a `-print` switch in `find`. Unfortunately, if I need piped commands, this would not do.

Obviously, `grep -H` wouldn't do either, because it will just say `(standard input)`.

How can I override "outgrepping" the file names? Print it on stderr somehow?

I realize I could save my file name in a variable, process it etc, but I'd love to see a simpler approach.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One simple way would be to say:

```
find . -type f -name "*.so" -exec sh -c "echo {} && readelf -s {} | grep mysymbol" \;
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks. To make it even clearer, I'd add `-print` to find: `find . -type f -print -exec sh -c "readelf -s {} | grep mysymbol" \;`

Comment: @PiotrZierhoffer Very nice.  Sometimes obvious stuff fails to occur.  Using `-print` is cleaner.

Comment: Minor nit: technically, `find` is only required to expand `{}` to the filename if that is the entire argument string.  For portability, it is common to write `-exec sh -c "readelf -s $0 ..." {} \;` and use a shell parameter to reference the file name.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you want something like this:

```
find . -name *.so -print0 | xargs -0 -I % sh -c 'echo % ; myCommand "%" | grep ExpectedResult'
```

Comment: Good answer, thanks! I've accepted devnull's answer while it's a bit clearer, but this one works as well. Nice `-I` in `xargs`, thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I think his solution is better than mine since I use unnecessary pipes.